# MSDEPLOY getting ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED. Where do I find out why?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, webdeploy

I'm trying to do a web deploy to a remote webserver (well, remote as in it's not the machine I'm trying to run MSDEPLOY on, it's in my local network.)

I've gone through the instructions here, to set up things on the webserver:

[configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler)

I have a web deploy package that works fine when I run it locally on the webserver:

```
mypackage.deploy.cmd /Y
```

When I run it from a different machine, specifying the server, I get ERROR_CERTIFICATE_VALIDATION_FAILED, which is no great surprise because the server has expired on the test server I'm working with.

```
mypackage.deploy.cmd "/M:https://myserver:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=mysite" /Y
```

The next obvious thing is to pass -allowuntrusted:

```
mypackage.deploy.cmd "/M:https://myserver:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=mysite" /Y -allowuntrusted
```

With this I get ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED, which is still no great surprise, because I'm not logged in as the user I've granted permissions to to the website directory.

So finally I try:

```
mypackage.deploy.cmd "/M:https://myserver:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=mysite" /Y /U:myuser /p:mypassword -allowuntrusted
```

And then I still get ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED.

When I browse around the web, I see a great many possibilities, some of which I've checked out. What I don't see is a clear explanation of how to tell which of these possibilities might actually be the problem.

Is there some logging, somewhere, where I could determine what, exactly, is going wrong?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy

Comment: Good info, but there's nothing in my "Microsoft Web Deploy" event log.

Comment: “By default, Web Deploy logs to the Event Log under Applications > Microsoft Web Deploy. **This is great place to start looking for errors on the destination server**.”

Comment: Like I said, there's nothing in the Microsoft Web Deploy log. My guess is that the authentication error is preventing the request from making it to Web Deploy.

Comment: The deployment also require user as a member of administrators group. Are you using a name like domain\user to deploy the website? You could try to enable process monitor on target server. Then do deployment and monitor whether access denied error was generated. Then you would know where you can grant permission

Comment: My understanding was that the whole reason for using MSDeploy.axd was so that a user who was not a member of the administrators group could push deploys.